# Sync / Transfer Spotify Playlist to Apple Music

Tags: music, playlist, spotify, apple-music

Is it possible to transfer all my Spotify playlist to the new Apple Music?

I have like 10 playlists with more than 5000 songs, I would hate to lose them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright I have found a way online to do it, the article was in Dutch so I will translate it for you all.

**Things you Need:**

1. MAC, preferred latest version
2. An TextEditor, if you don't have one get the free [TextWrangler](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/textwrangler/id404010395?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D8)
3. [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/latest-release/download.do), free to download proxy tool
4. Python 3, download the MAX OS X installer [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/python-3.4.3-macosx10.6.pkg)
5. [Spotify2Music](https://github.com/simonschellaert/spotify2am) script

**The process:**

**Step 1 - The Setup**

Create a folder on your desktop, this will be our working folder. Place the 2 files from the Spotify2Music zip in here.

[image: Spotify2Music Folder]

**Step 2 - Exporting the Playlists**

Login into [Exportify](https://rawgit.com/watsonbox/exportify/master/exportify.html) and extract the playlists you want. You can export the playlist by using the green buttons Export. Once you have done this successfully a window opens containing the CSV file. Select the whole file and create a file spotify.csv and place it in the desktop folder you created in step 1.

[image: Exporting playlists]

**Step 3 - Matching songs**

We must match the Spotify songs to Apple Music songs. Open a terminal and cd to the folder on the desktop (see Step 1). By this step you should have installed python 3. While in the Desktop folder type: python3 retrieve-identifiers.py. The script will start working.

[image: Matching songs]

**Step 4 - Retrieving the cookie from iTunes**

We are going to retrieve cookie data from iTunes using Charles Proxy.

1. From the Menu Proxy go to SSL Proxy Settings
2. Check 'Enable SSL Proxying'
3. Click on add and insert '*itunes.apple.com'
4. In the same Menu check on 'Mac OS X Proxy'
5. Go to iTunes go to an Apple Music playlist but don't do nothing
6. Check you have enabled recording (please refer to image below)
7. When recording is enabled add the playlist to my Music

[image]
[image]

When Charles is stopped go to to the tabs as shown in the screenshot above. Copy the fields (x-dsid, cookie, x-guid) to TextEdit or Word.

**Step 5 - Inserting the Cookie data**

The 3 data files we have just "stolen" from iTunes need to be inserted into 'insert-song.py'. Open this file with TextWrangler (or equivalent) and go to lines 30,31 and 32. Paste the x-dsid, cookie, x-guid data and save the file. Remember all files must be in the same folder.

[image]

**Step 6 - Ready to Import!**

Open a terminal navigate to the folder from Step 1 typ in 'python3 insert-songs.py' and you are now importing all the (Matched) Spotify to Apple Music.

[image]

**Tips and Tricks:**

I have made folders like this to enable a quick import of all my playlists. I suggest you do the same.
[image]

If you run into sync problems, check out this post http://www.idigitaltimes.com/apple-music-problems-how-fix-issues-syncing-playlists-icloud-library-offline-455939

**Remark**

Don't over do it! I had all the playlists open in tabs in my terminal and I overflowed the Apple Music buffer. This process takes time so do 1 playlist at a time and go sleep or take a nape or a coffee :)

**Credits**

All credits go to [This Post](http://www.onemorething.nl/2015/07/playlists-van-spotify-naar-apple-music-in-6-pittige-stappen/)

Comment: Running Charles actually prevents iTunes from authenticating Apple's servers, so before step 4 make sure to navigate to an Apple Music playlist within iTunes (you can't do this while Charles is running). Also, after recording the header attributes and inserting them into the script, quit Charles before running the script (otherwise the script fill fail as well).

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly, Apple is releasing an API to Apple Music (as evidenced by it's future appearance on Sonos), at which point this type of service will exist. As of now, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The [Applefy](https://github.com/ryanb93/Applefy) OS X app is pretty straightforward. Only requires OS X and iTunes. Follow the instructions from their README:

> - Open the application and log in with your Spotify details.
> - Select the playlist you want to transfer from the dropdown list.
> - Press the 'Save Playlist' button.
> - Navigate to your home folder and there will be a folder called Applefy.
> - Inside this folder will be a folder with your playlist name containing MP3s.
> - Open iTunes, go to the Playlists tab and make a new playlist.
> - Drag the MP3 files into the playlist.
> - Select all and right click. Choose 'Add to iCloud Music Library'
> - Once the songs have been registered, right click again and 'Remove download', you can now stream or download the full song using your Apple Music subscription.

Comment: This app is now discontinued, and no longer works, according to the README. `)=`

Answer (score 0):

I used an app called [Stamp](https://freeyourmusic.com/). It's a paid app but will do the job. It works by capturing the Apple Music session data, then adding the songs to iTunes. It will also double check to see if certain songs are already in iTunes. Pretty painless for the most part. So if you're looking for a solution that's a little less involved than the ones above, consider checking this app out.

Comment: This link appears to be dead, unfortunately.

Comment: I did also use an app called Stamp that is roughly similar and looks to be still active as well https://freeyourmusic.com/