# iTunes 12.2 import playlist issue

Tags: itunes, playlist, apple-music, spotify

I branched [Exportify](https://github.com/watsonbox/exportify) to output in an iTunes friendly format, and have used it to move my Spotify playlists over to iTunes.

It mostly works, except the import process seems incapable of adding songs from Apple Music which are not already in my Library. After running an import, I get a message saying "Some of the songs in the file “exportify.txt” were not imported because they could not be found.", which suggests it's only looking in my Library for songs to add.
It's possible to do this manually, so I don't see why letting the import process do it would be a problem...

Does anyone with experience with the iTunes importer know how to work around this (or has an alternative way to migrate playlists from Spotify)?

Comment: Following the steps in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193731/sync-transfer-spotify-playlist-to-apple-music worked ok for me in getting the songs into my library, I've created the playlists manually afterwards. What exactly are you doing differently?

Comment: Ooh, that looks promising - no, so far I was only using exportify to generate an iTunes formatted txt file, but your link seems to be able to take that and insert songs int my Library. Once that's done, I should be able to import the playlist the old fashioned way :) I'll try it later and post my results here, thanks!